# Linear convergence of simplified Newton-method proof

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods

In an old exam there is the following question

> Let $f:  \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be two times continuous differentiable with $f(x^*)=0$ and $f'(x^*)\not= 0$. Prove that $x_{k+1}=x_k- \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_0)}$ converges linear to $x^*$ if $x$ is close enough to $x^*$.

I have tried it using fixpoint iteration.
Let $\phi(x_{k})=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_0)}$, then $x^*$ is a fixpoint of $\phi$ because $$x^*=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}x_{k+1}=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\phi(x_k)=\phi(\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}x_{k})=\phi(x^*).$$
When I make use of the Mean Value Theorem I come to: 
$$
| x_{k+1}-x^*|=|\phi(x_k)- \phi(x^*)|=\phi'(\xi)|x_k - x^*|, \quad \text{with $\xi$ between $x_k$ and $x^*$}
$$
Wouldn't $L=\phi'(\xi)$ be enough to prove the linear convergences? The problem I have is that I don't know whether that is the correct way or false, because I don't use the "two times differentiable" anywhere for example. I figure maybe Taylor expansion would be another possible way but I did not try it.

Comment: I think that maybe baby Rudin establishes this fact on the way to proving the inverse function theorem. Might be worth checking.

Comment: $\xi$ depends on $k$ so $L=\phi'(\xi)$ is not a constant.

Comment: @little0 baby Rudin?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I guess you are right, do you have an idea on how to prove this?

Comment: You did not define $\phi$ properly. If you do that it follows immediately that $\phi(x^*) = x^*$ and that $f$ needs to be 2 times differentiable for using the mean value theorem. But yeah, Taylor expansion is the way to go.